# Open Inset Faces menu

Tags: mesh, faces

I want to adjust the Thickness of the "Inset Faces"-Tool manually, since dragging is very inaccurate, and I want the exact same thickness on every face of the cube. I googled around but didn't find how to open some sort of menu to type in the value. Help would be very appreciated.

Screenshot attached.
[image]

Comment: You can always just type in the desired value by typing while still being able to drag: You activate insert Faces and just type in 0.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like schustudrai says, or for more accuracy and options, make your inset and confirm it: parameters can then be edited on the bottom left in the "Operator" panel, or in a floating menu accessed using the <kbd>F6</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use snapping:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging to snap to increments
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for finer-grained snapping
- set snapping for all your edits using the magnet icon in the 3D view toolbar.